# Is it possible to use R-glm-offset as a multiplicative instead of within the exp-function value?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, offset

I have a dataset with a number of people at the start of the year and the status at the end of the year (either 0 for alive or 1 for deceased). In the dataset is the mortality probability from a life table (based on sex and age). Other variables are dummies for a.o. type of work and different diets.

I am using a logit model with the life table mortality probability as the offset (actually the log of that).

The problem is that the application that will use the results expects the experience factor as a percentage increase of the mortality probability. But using offset increases the odds and not the probability. Is there a way to get r-glm to output the logit-results as a factor on probability instead of odds? (or some way to rewrite ab/(1+ab) to a(x) where x does not contain a)

Comment: If make the offset multiplicative, you must use a log-link instead of a logit-link. There is no way to have both ways, i.e.., a logit link with a multiplicative offset.

Comment: I would imagine one possible setup to be modeling actual to expected, where "expected" would be your mortality proportion times the number exposed. You would be able to set this up as either a Poisson model (multiplicative) or as a binomial (log-odds, aka logit) model.Either of those options would fly with the R function `glm`.